# what's wrong when using jquery to call wcf service, always return internal server error?

Tags: wcf, jquery

Below is my jquery codes, and it always return internal server error, and i'm sure that my wcf service can be called from i.e and iis.

```
 $.support.cors = true;
         $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url:"http://localhost:8080/WcfService/FunHeartWork.svc/UpdateMedia",
            data: '{"desc":"' + text + '","albumId":"'+albumId+'","mediaId":"'+mediaId+'","userName":"'+userName+'"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
               alert(result);
            },
            error:function(a,b,c){alert(c);},
            failure: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Look at your web server logs to see what's going on.

Comment: Why are you writing `$.support.cors = true;`?

Comment: because i want to call from deferent project.

Comment: If you look at the request in fiddler does the JSON look as you're expecting?

Comment: Also turn on tracing in the service to see what it thinks is the problem

Comment: Hi Richard, now it can return data but what i got is an json format([abc:mydata]), how can I get my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the data line to:

```
data: {
  desc: text,
  albumId: albumId,
  mediaId: mediaId,
  userName: userName
},
```